# Limit space between td

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Here is my [form](http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/createleague.php)

As you can see there is a lot of space between the left side of information and the right side(input).  How do I limit this space?

```
<html><head><title>Create a League</title></head>

<body>

<center><h1>Create a League</h1></center>

<form action="" method="POST">

 <table cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr><td >League Name </td>
     <td> <input name="LeagueName" type="text"> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>Number of Members </td>
     <td><input name="Members" type="text"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>League Password </td>
     <td><input name="LeaguePassword" type="password"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan=><input name="Agreement" type="checkbox" value="1"> I agree with the terms of service</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan=""><input type="submit" value="Register" name="action">
     <input type="reset"  value="Reset"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use tables to markup your forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your colspan of the cell where the checkbox is to **colspan=2**, because without it whole checkbox with label is placed inside left column. After the change it will be spread through both columns so the left one with labels wouldn't have to be that wide.

```
<td colspan=2><input name="Agreement" type="checkbox" value="1"> I agree with the terms of service</td>
```